# How does a Cisco ACL handle fragments

Tags: cisco, security, cisco-commands, acl, fragmentation

We have an `ASR1000`, and I have the following ACL, but yesterday someone hit us with big DDoS attack, and I found it was a `DNS amplification` attack. so all source port for `53`, and it was definitely a fragmentation attack. See the following NetFlow data. I saw the router blocked some of the data, but some data sneaked in. In short it hit the internal servers.

Question: Why didn't the ACL stop this attack? How does the ACL handle fragmented packets here? The first packet contains port info, but the following fragmentaed packtes are `L3`, so how does a firewall handle them. We have `deny any any` in end, too.

Netflow

```
Top 10 Src Port ordered by bps:
Date first seen          Duration Proto          Src Port    Flows(%)     Packets(%)       Bytes(%)         pps      bps   bpp
2016-10-26 10:06:42.898  1207.930 any                   0    64619(49.0)   68.6 M(49.8)   86.7 G(57.2)    56826  574.5 M  1263
2016-10-26 10:06:42.754  1420.227 any                  53    46718(35.4)   47.1 M(34.2)   61.8 G(40.7)    33153  348.2 M  1313
```

ACL

```
ip access-list extended FOO-ACL
 permit udp any gt 1023 object-group VOIP-NET range 12000 13000
 permit udp any gt 1023 object-group SIP-NET eq 5060 
 permit udp object-group GOOGLE-DNS any
 permit tcp host any eq bgp host X.X.X.X
 permit icmp any object-group ICMP-NET echo-reply
 permit icmp any object-group ICMP-NET net-unreachable
 permit icmp any object-group ICMP-NET host-unreachable
 permit icmp any object-group ICMP-NET port-unreachable
 permit icmp any object-group ICMP-NET ttl-exceeded
 deny   ip any any
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not denying `fragments`. Cisco has an [Access Control Lists and IP Fragments](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/generic-routing-encapsulation-gre/8014-acl-wp.html) document that specifically deals with this problem.

> ### ACLs and Fragmented Packets
>
> ACLs have a **fragments** keyword that enables specialized fragmented
>   packet-handling behavior. In general, noninitial fragments that match
>   the Layer 3 statements (protocol, source address, and destination
>   address)—irrespective of the Layer 4 information in an ACL—are
>   affected by the **permit** or **deny** statement of the matched entry.
>   Note that the use of the **fragments** keyword can force ACLs to
>   either deny or permit noninitial fragments with more granularity.
>
> Filtering fragments adds an additional layer of protection against a
>   denial-of-service (DoS) attack that uses only noninitial fragments
>   (such as FO > 0). The use of a **deny** statement for noninitial
>   fragments at the beginning of the ACL denies all noninitial fragments
>   from accessing the router. Under rare circumstances, a valid session
>   might require fragmentation and therefore be filtered if a **deny
>   fragment** statement exists in the ACL. Conditions that might lead to
>   fragmentation include the use of digital certificates for ISAKMP
>   authentication and the use of IPSec NAT Traversal.
>
> For example, consider the partial ACL shown here.
>
> ```
> access-list 110 deny tcp any Internet routable subnet fragments
> access-list 110 deny udp any Internet routable subnet fragments
> access-list 110 deny icmp any Internet routable subnet fragments
> <rest of ACL>
> ```
>
> Adding these entries to the beginning of an ACL denies any noninitial
>   fragment access to the network, while nonfragmented packets or initial
>   fragments pass to the next lines of the ACL unaffected by the **deny
>   fragment** statements. The previous ACL snippet also facilitates
>   classification of the attack since each protocol—UDP, TCP, and
>   ICMP—increments separate counters in the ACL.
>
> Since many attacks rely on flooding with fragmented packets, filtering
>   incoming fragments to the internal network provides an added measure
>   of protection and helps ensure that an attack cannot inject fragments
>   by simply matching layer 3 rules in the transit ACL.
>
> Refer to [Access Control Lists and IP Fragments](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk827/tk369/technologies_white_paper09186a00800949b8.shtml) for a detailed
>   discussion of the options.

Comment: You are saying `deny any any` won't be able to stop `fragmente` packets, i thought if packet doesn't match to ACL then it should dropped in end.

Comment: It doesn't drop fragments. The `deny fragments` should be the first line in your incoming WAN ACL.

Comment: @Satish, multiple fragments will have the same rights to your network as the initial packet of the fragments. You want to deny all the other fragments that form the attack.

Comment: Got it, but is it ok to apply `fragments` on web traffic port `80` and `443`? i think web traffic sometime use fragments

Comment: That is discussed in the document that I linked.

Comment: I read it but still confused :( between all initia and non-initia stuff. My simple question is does it will break internet if i apply `access-list 101 deny tcp any any fragments` ? because we have web traffic too, and i believe web traffic use big packets sometime which may get fragmented

Comment: Most businesses don't allow fragments from the Internet into their networks. You don't want to do what you have in your comment. You want to use something like the partial ACL in the text block in my answer. if you deny all TCP port 80 packets, that will block the web server. You need to block inbound fragments from the Internet.

Comment: When a packet is fragmented into smaller packets, the initial packet fragment will be allowed. The subsequent packet fragments will be denied. Fragmentation is built into the DNA of IPv4, but it has proved problematic in attacks, so most people just deny fragments. IPv6, improving upon IPv4, has eliminated fragmentation.

Comment: Here i am confused, If someone download/upload something from/to Web server in that case packet will be `1500` or bigger don't you think that will blocked by `fragments` rules? or my concepts are wrong?

Comment: Don't confuse TCP segmentation with IP fragments. TCP will segment its data to a size meeting the MSS, and that will fit into the payload of the IP packets, which will be sized to fit the MTU. Fragmentation happens when the MTU along the path shrinks. Today, we have PMTUD to discover the minimum MTU along the path.

Comment: Holy smoke. now i got my answer :) superb!! i was confused there and you put last nail in coffin

Comment: @Satish: One word to the fragment keyword: "deny ip any any" of course does deny fragmented packets. Problem is, that those are permitted before. There is no layer 4 header in a non-initial fragment, hence no way for the ACL to match on port numbers. For those fragments, the specified port numbers of your existing ACLs are ignored and matching is done on IP information only. Example: for non-initial fragments, the first line of your ACL reads: "permit udp any object-group VOIP-NET". The main use case for the fragment keyword is to deny fragments only, in front of all permit statements.